# Hosting azure appfabric service bus samples on a development machine

Tags: wcf, azure, appfabric

I have been playing with some azure service bus samples and wanted to try out using the netEventRelayBinding for a publish/subscribe service. What I am curious about is how it can be tested locally through the test Azure environment (compute emulator or IIS). There must be something I am missing.

When building a url to bind to the service bus, it usually looks like sb://MySolution.servicebus.windows.net/MyService. I can't figure out how this translates to a local address and port. Is there any way to test Azure App Fabric services without having to sign up for an account and register a namespace on Microsoft's site? Anytime I try to run an Azure project or console app they are unable to bind to the url. Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the service bus is currently not emulated in the local fabric.

Comment: Running service bus locally does not defeat the point... it's highly needed :) ... I'm currently in a dev room working with 3 developers, running everything locally EXCEPT service bus. So, when I kick off a job, their computers start working on the task that I was trying to debug :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Service Bus 1.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj193022.aspx